# spotlight launches new emacs instead of moving focus to a running emacs instance

Tags: macos, mac, emacs, spotlight

Suppose I search for `chrome` in spotlight search, and select the top suggestion - `Google Chrome`, this causes mac os to move focus to a running instance of Google Chrome, if available. Likewise, when I search `iterm` inside spotlight search, it takes me to a running Iterm instance instead of launching a new one. This is how spotlight search works for all applications I tried.

However, when I search `emacs`, and choose the Emacs application from the top hits, it always starts a new instance of Emacs even though I have an instance of emacs running on my machine.

How do I make spotlight search bring the running emacs into focus as it does for other applications, instead of launching a new emacs instance?

Comment: When I used to use the very old emacs/XEmacs, there was an option in emacs whether to reuse an existing instance, or to open a new one, when you run a new "emacs" command in the terminal.  I don't know where you got the emacs you're running (a link would help!), but it's possible that that is still an option, so look through the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is easy... just launch emacs from spotlight. When you launch emacs from spotlight, then move focus to another application, and open spotlight search to launch emacs again, spotlight takes you back to the running emacs instance.

Whereas, when you launch emacs from the terminal, and then move focus to another application, and then try to go back to emacs from spotlight, spotlight launches a new emacs instance.

So, basically, I just had to launch emacs from spotlight in the first place instead of launching it from the terminal.